# An easy way to update Google Cloud DNS record with HTTP request

Tags: g-suite, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, dns-zone, dns-hosting

Is there a simple way to update a record of a managed zone in the Google Cloud DNS Platform, by means of something like an HTTP request. Some of the DNS providers allow for HTTP requests to be submitted with the record name, new record data and 'some authentication data' in the http string, which will then update the record in question on the DNS server.

I am aware of Google API (https://cloud.google.com/dns/api/v1/changes/create) however, isn't there a simpler method to request a record update? The reason I ask is that I would like to use some of the records in one of my zones as 'dynamic' records which will periodically be updated on network devices (in particular Mikrotik RB's). Therefore, I can't run an 'app' on these devices, nor use the authentication methods required by the GCP API, however, can do simple scripting and scheduling (with, hopefully, a simple http request).

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

J

Answer (score 2):

I don't actually understand the question. If you go to the [console explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/dns/v1/dns.changes.create), you can play and construct an API request, exactly as they will be issued by all the libraries. For example, if I want to add a new TXT record to my DNS zone I can issue a request like this:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/dns/v1/projects/{MY_PROJECT_ID}/managedZones/{MY_ZONE_ID}/changes?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

{
 "additions": [
  {
   "name": "example.com.",
   "type": "TXT",
   "rrdatas": [
    "my-data"
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```